# SGX Launch Control is Locked. Support SGX Virtuallization only - getting this message

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am using dual boot(Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) on my Dell XPS 8930 Desktop(2018). After GRUB screen, upon selecting Ubuntu Linux I am getting this message on black screen:
SGX Launch Control is Locked. Support SGX Virtuallization only [image]
After that is some disk check operation on my PCIE NVME drive(on which Ubuntu Linux is there).

What's those messages? How i can disable them as they slow down the boot process.